# How to run docker-compose as root user Docker Cloud

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, root

When I run as docker compose as ec2-user

```
[ec2-user@ip-15-0-52-106 $ docker-compose --version

docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

but as root user

```
[root@ip-15-0-52-106 ~]# docker-compose --version

-bash: docker-compose: command not found
```

I get command not found.

Any idea how to run it as a root user

Comment: What is the intention/advantage of running it as a root user?

Answer (score 1):

Default location of docker-compose is `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` but root does not contain path `/usr/local/bin`.

You can check is by following command:

```
[root@ip-172-31-40-117 ~]# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-117 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

You can add path for root, but it may not be a good way.(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115129/why-does-root-not-have-usr-local-in-path)

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-117 ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-172-31-40-117 ec2-user]# cd
[root@ip-172-31-40-117 ~]# vi .bash_profile

edit like this 
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

[root@ip-172-31-40-117 ~]# source .bash_profile
```

Or you can install docker-compose other path.